# Git doesn't seem to be adding new files

Tags: git, windows-7

I'm fairly new to using Git and haven't really dove into most of the features, just doing basic branch>add .>commit>merge.

I've recently made a ton of changes to the branch I'm currently in, and when I ran

```
git add .
```

I noticed it only picked up two new files instead of about 5.

I looked around and saw that I should check the tree to see if the new files are in there, so I ran

```
git ls-tree -r -t --name-only <branchName>
```

Sure enough, the files ARE NOT listed.

I ran git add . --force, but the only thing it added was a log file, not the JavaScript files I'm looking for.

Any reasons to why this might be? And any suggestions on how to fix it?

I assume as long as I stay in the current branch, I'm safe and don't have to worry about actually losing the files, but if I switch branches, won't the files be gone?

Comment: Are you running these commands from the top level of your repository? What does `git status` print?

Comment: What if you add them manually: `git add stuff.js` ?

Answer (score 1):

first of all you should check you .gitignore, maybe you have a pattern there which is matching your file.

Comment: wouldn't git add --force cause ignored files to be added as well?

Comment: I agree with Yads, the .gitnore file includes '.bundle, db/*.sqlite3, /log/*.log and tmp/**/*', none of which match the missing .js files.

Comment: ok, right, does your missing files have any peculiar file name?

Comment: there are multiple file names they are in my javascript folder and are 'aglo2.js' and 'algo.new.js'. so nothing earth shattering in the names.